# How can i addFlag to activity window on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

i want to addFlag to activity window.If i call this function before setContent method in Activity that's works but when i call this function in any Composable function that's not working.
I read all message writed before related this but not working in my case
[image]